# Метод onListItemClick: получение  данных  по  позиции

Tags: android

Доброго  времени  суток. Есть фрагмент. В  нем  курсор лоадер. В `ListView`  попадают  несколько  полей  из  бд. Как  используя  метод `onListItemClick`  получить  значение  определенного  поля???

Вот  код:

```
package ru.systemtehnolodgi.stav;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PlaceholderFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    android.app.LoaderManager loaderManager;
    private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> mCallbacks;

    final static Uri CATALOG_URI = Uri.parse("content://ru.htsprovider.htspdata/catalogtable");
    static final String CATALOG_NAME = "catalogname";
    static final String NAME_STATUS = "nstatus";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {

    }
    ScannerListCursorAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String[] from = new String[] { CATALOG_NAME, NAME_STATUS };

        adapter = new ScannerListCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item, null, from, null);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        mCallbacks = this;
        loaderManager = getActivity().getLoaderManager();
        loaderManager.initLoader(0, null, mCallbacks);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment_tehnolodgi, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bndl) {
        return(new CursorLoader(getActivity(), CATALOG_URI, null, null, null, null));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor c) {
         adapter.swapCursor(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
         super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
         Object obj;
         obj = getListAdapter().getItem(position);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "position = " + position + " " + obj.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понимаю в чем проблема. Почему не взять, например, значение поля с индексом 1 так:

```
@Override    
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
   String field1=adapter.getCursor().getString(1);
}
```

Comment: спасибо,  а  то  я  уже  извращаться  начал.